# Can a variable in FOL be bound by two quantifiers if they are the same

Tags: logic

∀x∀y((P(m) /\ Z(a,x)) > ∀xW(x,c))

Something like this. I don't think it is a sentence because the variable x is bound twice and the nested quantifier is still within the scope of the original quantifier. My friend disagrees with me and says it is a sentence because they are basically the same thing.

So, who is right

Comment: Yes the formula is correctly written.

Comment: The rightmost quantifier binds only the occurrence of x in W(x,c) while the leftmost one binds only the x in Z(a,c).

Comment: Havin said that, you can rewrite the formula with forall z W(z,c) and the meaning of the complete formula does not change.

Comment: As @MauroALLEGRANZA says, it's properly written but it's poor style.

Answer (score -1):

No, in first-order logic (FOL), a variable cannot be bound by two quantifiers if they are the same. This would result in a violation of the syntax and rules of FOL.
For example, in the expression ∀x∀x(P(x)), the variable "x" is bound by the universal quantifier ∀x twice within the same scope. This is not allowed in FOL. It would need to be rewritten as ∀x(P(x)) or ∃x∀y(P(x,y)), depending on the intended meaning.

Comment: Really?! But ∀x(P(x)) can be rewriten without changing meaning to ∀z(P(z)) and so the whole of your formula is identical to∀x∀z(P(z))

Comment: Please cite your sources. For example, in Metamath's intuitionistic propositional logic, there is [an axiom](https://us.metamath.org/ileuni/ax-i5r.html) which explicitly allows for nested first-order universal quantifiers. (I think that your answer is wrong, but if you provide evidence, then it could still get accepted.)